# SSRS - Run a report from another SSRS report run

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

How can I run a report whenever another report runs. I have a situation when an invoice report is executed by user, a copy invoice report should be executed for the same parameters provided to first report. I tried the action property of text to execute another report but nothing happened. How this text box trigger another report at the same time first report runs? Or if there is another way we can do this? There are no C#/Bn.Net code used to create or run report. Only SSRS controls or its related properties.  Thanks

Comment: Would a subreport work? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd220581.aspx

Comment: where do you want this copy to be run, is it on a different server?

Comment: yes on report server

Comment: How a subreport work on this? 
I want to print separate copy of same invoice.

Answer (score 0):

If you are administrator of your report server you can configure the history of your report.
go in the report properties, then go to the "instantatnious options" (sorry translated from french so don't know what'll give in english), and then select the checkbox "stock all instants of this report in the history"

that way every time the report is read a history of the report is stored